# Реализация SVM с нуля с помощью pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, машинное-обучение, model, pytorch

Добрый день всем машин лернерам! Нужна ваша помощь. Накидал план реализации SVM, но некоторые места не получается реализовать. Помогите, пожалуйста, кто чем может (желательно с комментариями).

```
def rbf(x1, x2, sig=1.):
    d = exp(- (np.sum(np.power((x1-x2),2))) / (2*sig**2))
    return torch.Tensor(d).type(torch.float32)

def hinge(scores, labels):
    #Cредний лосс для батча
    losses = max(0,1 - labels * scores)
    return np.average(losses)

class MYSVM(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def linear(x1, x2):
        #Линейное ядро
        return np.dot(x1,x2)

    def fit(self, X, Y):
        assert (np.abs(Y) == 1).all()
        n_obj = len(X)
        X, Y = torch.FloatTensor(X), torch.FloatTensor(Y)
        Kernel = self.kernel_function(X, X).float()
        self.bet = torch.full((n_obj, 1), fill_value=0.001, dtype=X.dtype, requires_grad=True)
        self.bi = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True) # Смещение
        
        opt = optim.SGD((self.bet, self.bi), lr=self.lr)
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            perm = torch.randperm(n_obj)  
            sum_loss = 0
            for i in range(0, n_obj, self.batch_size):
                inds = perm[i:i + self.batch_size]
                x_batch = X[inds]  
                y_batch = Y[inds]
                k_batch = Kernel[inds]
                opt.zero_grad()
                predictions = x_batch * self.bet[inds]  - self.bi #не уверен
                predictions = preds.flatten()
                loss = self.lmbd * self.bet[inds].T @ k_batch @ self.bet + hinge(predictions, y_batch)
                loss.backward()   
                optimizer.step()

                sum_loss += loss.item()

        self.X = X
        self.fitted = True
        return self

    def predict_scores(self, batch):
        with torch.no_grad():
            batch = torch.from_numpy(batch).float()
            Kernel = self.kernel_function(batch, self.X)
            #Значения отступа для каждого объекта в батче
            return ### ????????????

    def predict(self, batch):
        scor = self.predict_scores(batch)
        an = np.full(len(batch), -1, dtype=np.int64)
        an[scores > 0] = 1
        return an
```

Comment: Я думаю с таким вам лучше в Slack ODS - к профессионалам )

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что правильный ответ будет такой:

```
def predict_scores(self, batch):
    with torch.no_grad():
        batch = torch.from_numpy(batch).float()
        K = self.kernel_function(batch, self.X)
        # compute the margin values for every object in the batch
        return (K @ self.betas + self.bias).flatten()
```

Еще я бы поправил в функции fit:

```
predictions = x_batch @ self.bet - self.bi
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]